# Why can a point in anti-de Sitter space be modeled as a logical qutrit and how is its error correction done?

Tags: error-correction, quantum-state

This isn't my area but the recent Quanta article [How Space and Time Could Be a Quantum Error-Correcting Code](https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-space-and-time-could-be-a-quantum-error-correcting-code-20190103/) struck me as interesting. They mention:

> In their paper<sup>[1]</sup> conjecturing that holographic space-time and quantum
>   error correction are one and the same, they described how even a
>   simple code could be understood as a 2D hologram. It consists of three
>   “qutrits” — particles that exist in any of three states — sitting at
>   equidistant points around a circle. The entangled trio of qutrits
>   encode **one logical qutrit**, corresponding to a **single space-time point**
>   in the circle’s center. The code protects the point against the
>   erasure of any of the three qutrits.

The rest of the article more or less makes sense, but this is one point where I got stuck.

1. It's not very clear to me why one space-time point can be modeled specifically by a logical "qutrit"? What's so special about a "qutrit" in this context? Why not a "qubit" or a general "qudit"?
2. How exactly does the entangled trio perform the error correction of the central logical qutrit?

Note that I'm not acquainted with the AdS/CFT formalism. So an exposition aimed at a general audience is preferable.

<sup>[1]: [Bulk Locality and Quantum Error Correction in AdS/CFT (Almheiri *et al., 2014)*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.7041)</sup>

Comment: For the first question is it why one space-time point vs a spatial slice? Assigning a Hilbert space to a specific location when the actual Hilbert space is $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ using the entire space.

Comment: @AHusain No, but that point isn't clear to me either. Why exactly are they dealing with individual spacetime points, or as you say, assigning a Hilbert space to a specific spacetime point? Could you elaborate on it in an answer? (Even a partial answer might be good for a start.)